# How to properly Set Background Color of LWUIT Widget that is already themed?

Tags: java-me, colors, widget, lwuit

I tried the following code:

```
final Container root = getRootAncestor(c);
TextArea resultBox = findResultBox(root);

Style style = resultBox.getUnselectedStyle();
style.setBgImage(null);
style.setBgColor(0x00ff00);
style.setFgColor(0xff0000);
resultBox.setUnselectedStyle(style);
resultBox.setSelectedStyle(style);
```

What works is only the font/foreground color, however the background color persists (it still uses the background image from the theme). I also tried:

```
style.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED);
style.setBgImage(Image.createImage(1, 1, 0x00ff00));
```

But this also doesn't work.

Using LWUIT 1.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the background transparency to opaque: 255. Its possible that the color is just transparent. Creating a bgImage overrides color settings so make sure the image is set to null.

Comment: Thanks! style.setBgTransparency(255); does it!